# Date - Number of days filter in SOQL

Tags: soql

My SOQL Query is giving unknown parsing error. Whats the issue?

Select id, Account_Name__C, Account_Name__r.Email__c from QOACH_Conversion__c where LAU_CSAT_rating_of_IQOS_Coach__c= null AND CreatedDate= Date.today().addDays(-7)

Comment: Are you interested in the day seven days ago, or the last seven days?

Comment: day seven days ago

Comment: Apex code or an API call? Sorry, I should have asked that, too.

Comment: I am bulding the query in workbench/Query Editor. I cannot use apex

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The syntax you've quoted is only for Apex code (and needs a `:` prefixing it). There's also no such thing as the "between" operator in SOQL. As an alternative, you can use two date filters:

```
SELECT ... FROM ... WHERE ... AND CreatedDate = LAST_N_DAYS:7 AND CreatedDate != LAST_N_DAYS:6
```

Or, the apparently undocumented `N_DAYS_AGO` filter:

```
SELECT ... FROM ... WHERE ... AND CreatedDate = N_DAYS_AGO:7
```

Comment: It works, Thanks

Comment: FYI you can just filter `N_DAYS_AGO:7`.

Comment: @AdrianLarson It's not in the [docs](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_soql_select_dateformats.htm), so I didn't know about it. Guess we need a doc bug?

Comment: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/q/183620/2995

Comment: @AdrianLarson That link now goes to the same docs that do not have the N_DAYS_AGO filter .